# How to use Expanded with Future

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Part of my code is as follows:

```
     Expanded(
        flex: 13,
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(2),
          color: Colors.black12,
          child: FutureBuilder(
            future: getCompromissos(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (compromissosFiltrados != null && compromissosFiltrados.compromissos.length > 0) {
                return ListView.builder(
                  controller: ScrollController(),
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  itemCount: compromissosFiltrados.compromissos.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return CompromissoCard(
                        indice: index,
                        title: compromissosFiltrados.compromissos[index].nome,
                        icon: new Icon(icons[0], size: 24.0, color: Colors.green));
                  },
                );
              } else {
                return Container();
              }
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Sometimes `getCompromissos()` does not return any item and I have that empty space in my app.
[image]

I would like Expanded occupied all the space when there are nothing to show, like this:

[image]

In the lower part `Expanded( flex: 0` is working because contents of that widget don't come from the web.

But in this widget if I use `flex : 0` and there's not item, it's ok, but if there are items then I have errors like this:

> RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#6c79b
>   relayoutBoundary=up6 NEEDS-PAINT
>   'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart': Failed assertion: line 1694
>   pos 12: 'hasSize'

In case you need that part of `CompromissoCard`

```
  return new Container(
        color: Colors.white12,
        child: new Card(
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.white30,
            padding: new EdgeInsets.only(left: 5, top: 5, bottom: 5, right: 10),
            child: new Row(children: <Widget>[
              Column(children: <Widget>[
                SizedBox(height: 15),
                Column(children: <Widget>[new Image.asset("assets/images/meeting.png")])
              ]),
              Column(children: <Widget>[
                Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Column(children: <Widget>[
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 15,
                      ),
                      Text("13:00 - 14:00", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black38, fontSize: 16)),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 5,
                      ),
                      Text(this.title, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.w300))
                    ]),
                  ],
                ),
              ])
            ]),
          ),
        ));
```

I can't figure out how to do this.

Someone could help me? Thanks in an advance.